# Python Flask Swagger Flasgger Download Excel

Tags: python, flask, swagger, xlsx

I am trying to return an excel file from Swagger API. Built that using Flask with a Swagger wrapper with Flasgger. Here's the code -

```
@app.route('/cluster', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    """
    This API will help you generate clusters based on keywords present in unstructured text
    Call this api passing the following parameters - 
        Dataset Path - <hostname>\\<path to dataset>
        Column Name based on which clustering needs to be done
        Number of Clusters
    Sample URL: http://localhost:8180/cluster/clusters.csv?dataset=\\\\W1400368\\c$\\Users\\VK046010\\Documents\\Python%20Scripts\\RevCycle_PatientAcc.csv&ext=csv&col=SR_SUM_TXT&no_of_clusters=100
    ---
    tags:
      - Clustering API
    parameters:
      - name: dataset
        in: formData
        type: file
        required: true
        description: The fully qualified path of the dataset without the extension.
      - name: col
        in: query
        type: string
        required: true
        description: The column name on which the clustering needs to be done
      - name: no_of_clusters
        in: query
        type: integer
        required: true
        description: The number of clusters
    """    
    global data      
    data = data.fillna('NULL')



output = StringIO.StringIO()
data.to_csv(output,index=False)

resp = Response(output.getvalue(), mimetype="text/csv")
resp.headers["Accept"] = "text/csv"
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=clusters.csv"
return resp
```

This returns a downloadable link which I have to rename to csv to make it work.

**Question:** I am not being able to do this for excel files. No matter how I do it, once I download and rename, excel says the file is corrupt and that's that.

I tried pyexcel and pandas excel writer, didn't work out. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use flasgger to download excel. You can change the response type to "application/octet-stream" to resolve it.
[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the mimetype?

I think that the traditional mimetype for excel is `application/vnd.ms-excel`

You could find more details on microsoft files mimetype here: [What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)

Comment: thanks Chester yes I did! I tried both `application/vnd.ms-excel` and `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`. I could download the file, rename it to myfile.xlsx but I get error saying file is corrupted. If i open it in notepad its a lot of junk characters that I see...